# how to fetch data from spreadsheet with axios?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, axios

So I have this piece of code, it grabs data from google spreadsheet, and returns JSON.
I tried implementing the same functionality with my google spreadsheet document, but for some reason it returns **403 error**.

Is it even possible to make requests like that anymore? And if so, how can I make such a request?
It seems that google spreadsheets API got updated.

```
import axios from 'axios';

let data = null;

function fetch() {
  const spreadsheetID = "id_of_the_spreadsheet_document";
  const url = `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/${spreadsheetID}/od6/public/values?alt=json`;

  return axios.get(url)
    .then(res => {
      data = res.data.feed.entry
      // do data transformation here  
      // then simply return it
      return data;
    });
}

export default {
  fetch,
  get: () => data,
}
```

Comment: A 403 error means 'Forbidden' which might suggest you don't have permission to access the spreadsheet. Have you checked the API for any type of authentication?

Answer (score 0):

The [Error 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) informs you that you doesn't have the required permission to access the Sheet. You should manage a token relationship with the Spreadsheet API. You can do it following the [JavaScript Sheets API Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs), where you can find workable examples that you can later modify to add your code. Please, ask me if you have any doubt whatsoever.